# Websocket: Error 1006 on python after 50-60 seconds

Tags: python, websocket

Already read all questions and answers here about error 1006 on websockets, I understand what the error means but can't find what's wrong.
When pinging the wss server on postmates I dont get any error and manage to keep the connection open, however when doing it in python I get a 1006 error after 50-60 seconds.
I don't have access to the server. Any ideas?

My code is:

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

def runit():    

    url = "wss://"
   
    async def test():
        async with websockets.connect(uri=url, ping_interval=10) as websocket:
            try:

                print("waiting")
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({"action": "ping"}))
                
                async for msg in websocket:
                                if msg:         
                                    dic = json.loads(msg)
                                    print(dic)
                                   
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                print("connection closed")
                await websocket.close()
    asyncio.run(test())
    

# start bot
runit()
```

this is what I get on my console after the last ping pong:

```
% sending keepalive ping
> PING 44 bd 03 c0 [binary, 4 bytes]
< PONG 44 bd 03 c0 [binary, 4 bytes]
% received keepalive pong
! failing connection with code 1006
= connection is CLOSED
```